# functionsgenerator - arithmetic logic unit

Tags: digital-logic

Given that

```
If ABCDE = 11000 then S = X + Y
If ABCDE = 11011 then S = X - Y
If ABCDE = 10001 then S = X + 1
```

[image]

What should be the value of `ABCDE` for implementing following functions?

```
S = X + Y
S = X - Y - 1
S = X - 1
S = 0000
S = 1111
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data provided, It is clear that:

1. the block labeled `&` ANDs each bit of input `X` with its control signal `A`.

   `output = 0000 if A = 0
           = input if A = 1`
2. the block labeled `=1` XORs each bit of input with its control signal `C`.

   `output = input if C = 0
           = -1-input if C = 1` (1's complement of input)
3. `Adder` performs:

   `S = input1 + input2 + E`

Since we know what each bock does, it is easy to implement the functions given in the question. Let me do the first one for you.

We have to implement the function `S=X+Y`, then inputs to the adder must be `input1=X`, `input2=Y` and `E=0` so that `S=X+Y+E = X+Y+0 = X+Y`

then, `ABCDE` must be `11001`.

```
-----------------------------------------------
function        input1   input2    E     ABCDE
-----------------------------------------------
S = X + Y         X        Y       0     11001
S = X - Y - 1     X      -Y-1      0     11010
S = X - 1         X       -1       0     10010
S = 0000          0        0       0     00000                 
S = 1111        
------------------------------------------------
```

I think now you can do the remaining by your own and fill the blank fields in the table.

Comment: <pre>-----------------------------------------------
function        input1   input2    E     ABCDE
-----------------------------------------------
S = X - Y - 1     x        y       1     11000
------------------------------------------------<pre/>

Comment: input1 = x      ------ input2 == y  and E = 1 so the ABCDE will be = 11000 right

Comment: @user2393690 Nop. You got it wrong. `input1` and `input2` are inputs of the adder. So for `X-Y-1`, `input1=X`, `input2=-Y-1` and `E=0`

Comment: so its will be ABCDE = 11011, for X-Y-1 ?  or 11010 :P

Comment: `11010`. A=1 and C=0 will make input1=X. D=1 will invert Y and hence input2 will be -1-Y. E =0. then S=X-Y-1.

Comment: S = x- 1 =====> ABCDE = 10010 ? , because A=1 and C=0 will make input1 =X. B=0 and D = 1 will make input2 = 1111(-1) and E=0 right ?

Comment: Good. You are on the right track. :) 2 more to go

Comment: Iam on the right track because of you, Your my hero man <3. S = 0000 , If A = 0 and C = 0 and input1 will be 0, same with B and D both are 0 and input2 will be 0. E should be also 0.Then ABCDE = 0000 ?

Comment: Yes. it is 00000.

Comment: Now the lastone S=1111, A =0 C = 0 ===> input1 = 0. B=0 D = 1 ===> input2 = 1 and E = 0, so the ABCDE will be 00010   :-)?

Comment: Yes. it is 00010.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the very good explanation, woow now iam done with this, before your help i was totally lost. <33333333